# Eclipse unable to resolve plugin org.eclipse.wst.server.ui

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

I tried using Eclipse after not using it for some time and I get this error:

```
    !MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui/icons/cview16/servers_view.gif".
```

The .log includes quite a few similar messages. I have checked the plugins folder and it seems all of the files in it are missing. I have been unable to find these files anywhere, even on a fresh installation.

I've looked all over Google and StackOverflow and I still have no answer, especially when the last time I started up Eclipse, I did not have this error and I have never touched this folder in the past.

More of the error log is here http://pastebin.com/kiejQThE

Comment: Have you tried with the current version?

Comment: `org.eclipse.wst` is part of the web tools component of Eclipse. If you have done a new install you may not have installed WST (it is not included in some Eclipse downloads). You can install it from `Help > Install New Software`.

Comment: @greg-449 Unfortunately, Eclipse crashes on startup, so I cannot access `Help > Install New Software`. Is there somewhere else I can find it? If not, can I remove dependencies on it so it doesn't crash?

Comment: The 'Eclipse IDE Java EE Developers' download on the [Eclipse downloads site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) looks like it might contain enough of WST.

Comment: @greg-449 Okay, I've added the entire WST library, and it still throws exactly the same error.

Comment: My answer on this link will solve all of the plugin issues (with this specific message) if you start from scratch without a workspace folder.  Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530251/failure-to-rename-an-eclipse-plugin-unable-to-resolve-plug-in

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem.  In my case, Java was displaying an error about a different .gif file in wst.

I tried greg-449's advice (greg-449 Feb 25 '14 at 8:16) of installing org.eclipse.wst .

That solved the problem of the missing .gif file.