# Failure to rename an eclipse plugin (Unable to resolve plug-in)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, resources

I am working on an eclipse plugin. After some marketing people got in the way, I need to rename my plugin. So I went ahead and opened the plugin.xml in eclipse and changed the name and ID in the overview TAB.

Then, when I try to launch eclipse to see everything is working, it dumps a whole lot of prints about not being able to resolve plugin (I removed the name of the old plugin for IP reasons, sorry):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2014-07-02 14:19:08.885
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/<PREVIOUS NAME REMOVED>/icons/new_kb_cube.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/OpenCL_SDK/icons/new_kb_cube.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:112)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Any idea on how to clean it? I tried the eclipse project clean but it didn't help...

Thanks,
Oren

Comment: Did you also rename the project?

Comment: Hi nitind - The project name was different in the first place (from the old name and new). So I didn't. Should I?

Comment: It probably is not the cause, then.

Comment: Have to tried specifying the -clean option when you start Eclipse to get it to refresh its caches?

Comment: Hi Greg, I have - and it's not that. It still shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was to remove the workspace folder that Eclipse stores its files in, and then re-opened Eclipse, and had it default to that same path with a clean start.  I had opened a new version of Eclipse, which caused my issue.  So it was still using the same configuration the previous version had, and was probably a little more complex than changing a single configuration setting.

Answer (score 3):

OK, issue solved. I had to do a full workspace clear in the Main tab of the run configuration and the error was gone.

Hope this helps someone :-)

Oren

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. Please note that if you are running the plugin on a different workspace, you have to uncheck the 'Use default location' checkbox and select the workspace from the 'Configuration' tab

Answer (score 0):

Check the Configuration tab of your Eclipse Application launcher, and make sure you're Clearing the configuration area before launching.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that too and the same error still shows.

Comment: Since this is a problem with a specific file in the plug-in, are you referring to that icon in the plugin.xml without also having changed the MANIFEST.MF file that gives the plug-in its name?

Comment: No, when I wrote above that I edited the plugin.xml file, I meant I did this by opening the plugin tab that has the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml (which holds the Overview, Dependencies, Runtime, Extensions, etc.). There's no more reference to the old name anywhere in the plugin, at lease by searching with the "File search" option. Still, it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in). I also did a full workspace clear in the Main tab of the run configuration and the error was gone.